# ISPF Editor: Changing characters to upper case?

Tags: zos

I am fairly new to working in a z\OS environment, I've tried Googling this but found no result.

I'm creating a data set member in the `ISPF` edit window. However, every time I exit out of the file, save it, try to submit it as a `JCL` job, it will convert all the characters to upper case.

How can I stop this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While in ISPF Edit on a member, if you type `PROFILE` on the "Command===>" line and press Enter, you will likely see `CAPS ON` included in your current options.  You can change this by doing the following...

```
PROFILE UNLOCK
CAPS OFF
PROFILE LOCK
```

...on the Command===> line, pressing Enter after each.

The [ISPF documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=ispf) is quite extensive.  The above are what ISPF calls [primary commands](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-edit-primary-commands).  The ISPF editor is quite powerful, there are [SHARE presentations](https://www.share.org) on its features.

ISPF Edit also has [line commands](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-edit-line-commands), entered by overtyping the line number for a given line.  Two such are `UC` and `LC`, which correspond to Upper Case and Lower Case respectively.  They do just what you'd think, the former folds all text to upper case and the latter folds all text to lower case.  Numbers and special characters are unaffected.

Comment: Be aware that if you set CAPS to OFF, and you then edit a new member in a PDS with the same low level qualifier that has no lower case letters, ISPF will flip the CAPS setting back to ON. ("Low level qualifier" is the last part of the data set name, e.g., with MY.PROD.CNTL, CNTL is the LLQ.)

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr Even with the Profile locked?